# Homotopy type of a CW complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

The only dimension in which not every compact manifold is homeomorphic to a CW complex is $4$. Does every such manifold have the homotopy type of a CW complex?

Comment: Yes http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156266/reference-request-compact-manifolds-with-boundary-have-the-homotopy-type-of-a-c#156272

Comment: Yes, see Corollary A.12 of Hatcher's book.